# Remove a keychain from search list?

Tags: keychain

This is asked as a follow up as this SO:

[Add a keychain to search list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538942/add-a-keychain-to-search-list)

We know how to add a new create keychain to the search list by:

```
security list-keychains -s `security list-keychains | xargs` $NEW_KEYCHAIN
```

However, how do we remove it afterwords? After calling this multiple times (intentionally), we end up having this:

```
$ security list-keychains
"/Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
"/Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/foo.keychain-db"
"/Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/foo.keychain-db"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

Notice that we have multiple entries of `foo.keychain-db` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be ideal, but we can simply call it again with the entries that we want to keep. For example, in this case:

```
$ security list-keychains -s /Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

And it will be the result that we want:

```
$ security list-keychains
"/Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```