# how to add new custom keychain to keychain list in mac

Tags: macos, security, amazon-ec2, keychain

Using Amazon ec2 mac in which default keychain location is `"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"`

Created new keychain in the location `/home/ec2-user/Library/Keychains/abc`

When i execute `security list-keychains`, it shows only

```
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

how to add my newly created keychain as part of list-keychains, so it can be viewed when we execute `security list-keychains`.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538942/add-a-keychain-to-search-list

Comment: @NickK9 - I tried this before. but didnt help.

Comment: security -v list-keychains -s <keychain> didnt work. but with sudo it works